# order, group and search query. too many selects

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

i am running this query, witch consists of 3 recursive selects.

```
select idigorUserFields 
from ( select * 
       from ( select * 
              from igorUserFields f
              where f.idigorUsers = 1
              order by f.idigorUserFields desc) tbl
       group by tbl.idigorUserFieldTemplates ) tbl2
where value="qf" and idigorUserFields = 28
```

what I am trying to do is simple:

- get all fields, order by insert date ( i am using primary key for that )
- get the last inserted value for a field (idigorFieldTemplates)
- compare the last inserted field with the one i am about to insert, to save some space on the database

some relevant info:

- idigorUserFieldTemplates is the primary key for a "html user fields table"
- the last inserted value is the one displayed on the program

also, I have a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2df7bf/7)! with some data to test.

my question is: can I make this query better?  and what do I need to use to do that.

Comment: why are you using another select for ordering and grouping? MySQL will group in any order it pleases.

Comment: And why are you 'selecting' when it seems you really want to be 'inserting' !?!?!

Comment: I want to compare the just last inserted value, in order to avoid duplicate consecutive entries in the database

Comment: @ruifn if its just the last inserted value then why not get the max(idigorUserFields)?

Comment: @john-ruddell you're right, thanks for the answers. with max(idigorUserFields) and where's in the right place, I've managed to get a better query for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so it looks like you want to get the last inserted value for a given user and value and then compare that with the data you are about to insert. Here's how I would tackle that

```
SELECT a.idigorUserFieldTemplates
FROM igorUserFields AS a
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(idigorUserFields) as max_id FROM igorUserFields WHERE idigorUsers = 1 AND value="qf") AS b
ON a.idigorUserFields= b.max_id
```

The subquery is giving me the largest idigorUserFields for which idigorUsers = 1 AND value="qf." For this to work, you have to assume that that the primary key (idigorUserFields) is incrementing with date. You indicated in your post that it does, so hopefully this assumption is okay.

Once we've got that last updated record, we then join back with igorUserFields to get the corresponding value of idigorUserFieldTemplates

edit:
I want to get the last inserted for a given user and field. then compare it with what i am about to insert.
I am sorry if I was not clear enough about what I wanted.
I modified the above sql and i got what i wanted:

```
SELECT a.* FROM igorUserFields
AS a INNER JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(idigorUserFields) as max_id
FROM igorUserFields WHERE idigorUsers = 1 and idigorUserFieldTemplates =6) AS b 
ON a.idigorUserFields= b.max_id
AND value="qf"
```

thanks! now I got a more efficient solution :)

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is the largest id by specific data just specify that order it and limit it like so

```
SELECT idigorUserFields 
FROM igorUserFields 
WHERE idigorUsers = 1 AND value="qf"
ORDER BY idigorUserFields DESC
LIMIT 1
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2df7bf/11)

if you are trying to get the last inserted value then you can get the largest idigorUserFields assuming its auto incremented.

```
SELECT MAX(idigorUserFields) FROM idigorUserFields
```

and then if you want a specific column from that field you could use it as a subquery

```
SELECT f.idigorUserFieldTemplates 
FROM idigorUserFields f
WHERE f.idigorUserFields = 
(   SELECT MAX(idigorUserFields) 
    FROM idigorUserFields
    WHERE idigorUsers = 1 AND value="qf"
)
```

Comment: thanks, but that is not what i am looking for. i want to compare just the last inserted value for "idigorUserFieldTemplates". that value can be equal to older entries, but not the last one.

Comment: @ruifn well from what you've provided theres not much we can do for you... im not just getting the last one, its the largest (aka the last) id by user = 1 and value = qf.. thats what your query looked like it was trying to do. can you help me understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have a page witch displays the last inserted values by idigorFieldTemplates, where you can edit them. if you save, it sends those values back. I want to verify if the values i am about to receive, compare with the last displayed value ( max id, grouped by idigorFieldTemplates ) and see if is a match or not.